# How do I correctly Expose a property on a custom control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a custom control in `Xamarin.Forms` and expose a property correctly. I'm sure the same principals apply to `WPF`

**My Control**

```
public class ExtendedMap : Map
{
    public ExtendedMap()
    {

    }

    private IList<Pin> _staticPins;
    public IList<Pin> StaticPins
    {
        get { return _staticPins; }
        set { _staticPins = value;}
    }
}
```

And in **Xaml** I am currently using it like so:

```
<custom:ExtendedMap x:Name="map" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" IsVisible="{Binding CustomerSearchControlViewModel.MapIsDisplayed}">
  <custom:ExtendedMap.StaticPins>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type maps:Pin}">
      <maps:Pin Label="Hello" Address="{Binding CustomerSearchControlViewModel.SelectedCustomer.Address, Converter={StaticResource AddressToStringConverter}" Position="{Binding CustomerSearchControlViewModel.SelectedCustomer.Position}" Type="Place"/>
    </x:Array>
  </custom:ExtendedMap.StaticPins>
</custom:ExtendedMap>
```

If I take the `<x:Array>` part out I get an error:

> Sequence is not IEnumerable

but I would like to use it like:

```
<custom:ExtendedMap.StaticPins>
      <maps:Pin Label="Hello" Address="{Binding CustomerSearchControlViewModel.SelectedCustomer.Address, Converter={StaticResource AddressToStringConverter}" Position="{Binding CustomerSearchControlViewModel.SelectedCustomer.Position}" Type="Place"/>
 </custom:ExtendedMap.StaticPins>
```

Is this possible? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: take a look at `IList<T> Interface` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to be looking?

Comment: what do you mean.. I just gave you the link.. sounds like you have an `IEnumerable` issue going on..

Comment: @MethodMan I mean I can see the Enumerable API documentation but I don't understand how that links/solves my issue? Sorry if I'm missing something

Comment: well look at this solution here then https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55473/is-it-possible-to-use-xamarin-maps-to-add-map-pins-in-xaml

Comment: @MethodMan: is that second link just this exact question? I.e. it looks to me like the OP here also posted the messages on that other page.

Comment: @PeterDuniho well spotted. That is the exact same question on another forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [What is the worst gotcha in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957892)

> 3) Property's type must implement `IList`, not `IList<T>`, if the property is to be recognized by XAML as a collection property.

More generally, XAML and generic types don't work very well together, unfortunately.

If that does not address your concern, please improve your question. Provide [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, so that it is more clear what the scenario is.

You may also be interested in [How Can I Nest Custom XAML Elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1174853), which shows how you can declare a property as the default collection for child elements in XAML.

Comment: Your first point was spot on. I had to Implement `IList` not `IList<T>`. I will post my actual solution later.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Peter Duniho's answer it forced me in the right direction. It was a combination of the points he mentioned.

Firstly I had to implement `IList` on my `ExtendedMap` so that I could set the List of items in `Xaml` without using an `Array`

The final solution looked like so:

```
public class ExtendedMap : Map : IList
{
    public ExtendedMap()
    {

    }

    private IList<Pin> _staticPins = new List<Pin>();
    public IList<Pin> StaticPins
    {
        get { return _staticPins; }
        set { _staticPins = value;}
    }

    //..IList Implementations

    Public int Add(object item)
    {
       var pin = (Pin)item;
       StaticPins.Add(pin);
       return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that you chose to implement `IList` in the class itself, rather than adding `[ContentProperty("StaticPins")]` to the declaration, because the former approach allows you to preserve the generic `IList<Pin>` on the property type while the latter would not. If that's true, you might want to add a comment to your answer above to make that clear to future readers, so that they can understand better the trade-offs between the two options.